# Get the sum of numbers from array objects

Tags: javascript

I want to get the sum of all array items.

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }];

const app = (arr) => {
    const r = arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
        return acc[Object.keys(acc)] + nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)]
    })
    return r
}
console.log(app(arr))
```

So, at the end i want to get: `8` = sum of: `{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }`.
Question: Why now i get `NaN` as a result?

Comment: What do you expect what `acc[Object.keys(acc)] + nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)]` does? `Object.keys()` returns an array. In this case it works, but only because there's only one property in every object.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Add a `console.log()` in the `.reduce()` and check the values

Comment: You are missing the initialiser in `reduce`. But moreover, you're not using the `reduce` callback correctly - note that the *return value* becomes `acc` next time the callback is invoked, so if you return a number `acc[Object.keys(acc)]` will try to get a property off a number. Finally `[Object.keys(acc)]` itself is a potential problem, as `Object.keys` returns an array and in most cases, that will not fetch anything specific from an object.

Answer (score 2):

You need a start value of zero and the first key of the keys array, not the whole array.

For summing take the accumulator directly.

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }];
const app = (arr) => {
    const r = arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
        return acc + nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)[0]];
    }, 0);
    return r;
};

console.log(app(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add initialValue 0  to reduce

```
const app = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
        return acc + Object.values(nextValue)[0]
    } ,0)
   
console.log(app(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to point that you want to return a number from reducer,  and out initial value type number as a second parameter in your function

```
const app = (arr) => {
        const r = arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
          console.log(nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)]);
          return acc + nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)];
        }, 0);
        return r;
      };
      console.log(app(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple, you making it difficult. You need values not keys and to make sure use `Number()` function

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }];

const app = (arr) => {
    const r = arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
        return acc += Number(Object.values(nextValue))
    },0)
    return r
}
console.log(app(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj)).flat().reduce((acc, next) => acc += next)

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }]

const arrayMap = arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj)).flat().reduce((acc, next) => acc += next)

console.log(arrayMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand what `reduce` is?
Consider this following custom implementation:

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }];

const reduced = (array, instructionToCombine, buildingUpOn) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    buildingUpOn = instructionToCombine(buildingUpOn, array[i][Object.keys(array[i])]);
  }
  return buildingUpOn;
}

const instructionToCombine = (a, b) => a + b;

const ans = reduced(arr, instructionToCombine, 0);
console.log(ans)
```

Now, you got how *JavaScript* default `reduce` method works.

You're missing the `initialValue` (`buildingUpOn` in my implementation). Know that, `initialValue` is not *required* parameter, rather it's optional. Yet,

> If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be
> used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as currentValue - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

But you treated otherwise that's why didn't get the expected answer. `acc` is a object for the first iteration, but rest of the iteration it's a number but you treated like a object which returned undefined and, sum of a `Number` with `undefined` returns `NaN`.

**If you still need to achieve this without passing the `initialValue`**, it's very possible by keeping `acc` an object this way:

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 5 }, { c: 2 }];

const app = (arr) => {
    const r = arr.reduce((acc, nextValue) => {
       
        const newValue = acc[Object.keys(acc)] + nextValue[Object.keys(nextValue)];
        return {x: newValue};
    })
    return r[Object.keys(r)];
}
console.log(app(arr))
```